# Exit from all nested shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How to exit from all nested shell script calls once in a single command?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can't (except via something like `kill`). One process (e.g. a subprocess running a nested script) cannot tell other processes (e.g. its parents) what to do. Mind you, you could exit the subprocess with an error status and write all the calling scripts to exit when the child script exits with an error, but this has to be written into all of the scripts.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That seems like an answer. Would you be willing to post it (or something like it) as one?